# how to use user authorize in laravel based on query select eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, authorization

So, to put it simply, suppose I have a members table with columns

```
[
  'id', 'name', 'phone', 'province'
]
```

Users table

```
[
  'id', 'email', 'password', 'role_id'
]
```

Operator access table

```
[
  'user_id', 'province'
]
```

Roles table

```
[
  'id', 'role'
]
```

For available roles **(admin, operator)**

Role admin can access all member data, while Role operators can access only one province

How to create an authorize checker if the user operator is not allowed to access / update / delete / store the members table apart from the province itself

Do I have to use Gate authorize? How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this through the use of middleware:
If the user has already been authenticated and within the middleware function, (pre-middleware action)

```
$user_role = Role::find(Auth::user()->role_id)->role;
if ($user_role == 'operator') {
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'You do not have the permission to visit this resource'
    ], 401);
} else {
    // Move on to the request
}
```

You could modify this function as needed

Answer (score 0):

You can check permission in middleware. if the page has permission is accessable to user or not

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = Auth::guard('admin')->user();
           
        if ($user->role == 0) {   //Allow all for Admin
            return $next($request);
        }

        $role = Role::where('_id', $user->role)->first();
        $a = $request->segment(2); 
        if (isset($role->permissions[$a])) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect('admin');
    }
```